# How to sort by "_id" in document and embedded documents in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993e9ee92cf241648002a97"),
    "name" : "test"
    "subcategories" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59953f20f4b8cf0595720e62"),
            "name" : "subtest",
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59953f20f4b8cf0595720e63"),
            "name" : "subtest2",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993e9ee92cf241648002a98"),
    "name" : "test2"
    "subcategories" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59953f20f4b8cf0595720e66"),
            "name" : "subtest3",
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59953f20f4b8cf0595720e69"),
            "name" : "subtest4",
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to sort both, documents and embedded documents by _id using mongoose.

Something like this:

```
categoryModel.find({ }).sort({ _id: 1, "subcategories._id": 1 }).exec(function (err, data) {});
```

But i know just **"_id: 1"** will work.
How can do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Sort the "documents" returned? Or "sort the array elements **within** the documents" returned? Also is there some reason why the array cannot be "stored" in the defined order? And note that by default, any array has "latest last" because that's what happens when you append.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just update my question

Comment: You can select all `categories`, and sort `subcategories` on server side: `...exec()
.then(cats => {
  cats.each(cat => cat.subcategories.sort((a, b,) => a._id.toString() - b._id.toString()));
  return cats;
});`But why you need do that, when `subcategories` array is already ordered by `_id`?

Comment: Are you doing more write or more read on this collection? especially for subcategories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with JS

```
subcategories.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a._id.toString().localeCompare(b._id.toString());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort subdocument with populate function and sort option.

```
categoryModel
    .find({})
    .populate(
        {path: 'subcategories', options: { sort: { '_id': -1 } } }
     )
```

Comment: I think populate is for two models, I just have one model